# I installed both python 2.7 and 3.5, but python 3.5 does not work well

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In terminal, I can run `py -2` successfully.
Nevertheless,

```
C:\Users\user>py -3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00004570 (most recent call first):
```

Comment: I'm guessing using `python3`instead of `py -3` doesn't work on your system?

Comment: There's a chance that there is a conflict when accessing python from the environment variables. So walk to the path where python3 is installed and then use the command.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the "PYTHONHOME" environmental variable.
(This resolved my problem when installed python27 x86 and python36 x64)

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting python path.

```
C:\Users\user>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.5;%PATH%
C:\Users\user>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\python_lib_path
C:\Users\user>python
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem.
I found that my python 2.7 is *x86* and my python 3.5 is *x64*, so I deleted both of python 2 and 3, then reinstall python 2.7 and 3.5 as *x64*, then it works.

[My install applications are shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pKEG.png)