# incompatible codecs in module "encodings.utf_8"

Tags: python, pycharm

When I **DEBUG** my code in pycharm, I meet the error below. However, the code is running fine in terminal.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/dj/tools/pycharm-2018.2.1/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 382, in _on_run
>       r = r.decode('utf-8')   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py", line 134, in
>   search_function
>       (mod.**name**, mod.**file**) CodecRegistryError: incompatible codecs in module "encodings.utf_8"
>   (/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc)

my code is simple:

```
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import

import shutil
import glob
import os
import random


def run():
    src_dir = '/home/dj/result/'
    dst_dir = '/home/dj/tmp/'

    clear_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(dst_dir, '*.jpg'))
    for path in clear_paths:
        os.remove(path)

    all_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(src_dir, '*.jpg'))

    check_paths = random.sample(all_paths, 10)

    for select_path in check_paths:
        _, file_name = os.path.split(select_path)
        save_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_name)
        shutil.copy(select_path, save_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I google this question but not help. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Error != code example. Check about pycharm debbuger, something like uncheck the option "Collect run-time types information for code insight".    https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207276509-Debugger-step-over-works-differently-in-2016-2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have try to selected or unselected that option, but it didn't help. @Mate

Comment: did you try to run it out of pycharm?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `# coding: utf-8` magic comment on top?

Comment: The code is running fine in terminal. @Mate

Comment: Same error when I remove # coding: utf-8 on top. I think it may be the problem with pycharm? But I don't know the solution. @HåkenLid

Comment: Linked (with no solution except reinstalling python): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649056/encodings-codecregistryerror-while-using-pycharms-remote-debugger

Comment: I have tried that, but not help. @iamanigeeit

Comment: do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: yep, I have python2.7.12 and python3.5.2. @iamanigeeit

Comment: seems like you need to edit your PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH or remove them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529960/i-installed-both-python-2-7-and-3-5-but-python-3-5-does-not-work-well

Answer (score 1):

I answer for myself.

- Actually, I don't have a solution yet. My solution is re-install
  ubuntu and install anaconda.
- I think the reason of this problem is something wrong with the python
  environment. To prevent this unbearable problem happen again, I use
  anaconda to create multiple python environment.